# Asp.Net MVC Ajax.BeginForm not working when loaded by Jquery Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC view and in that view, on clicking on a button, I am hitting the server using Jquery ajax request and returning a partial view.

This partial view includes Ajax.BeginForm. When submit happens in this Ajax.BeginForm, it is throwing javascript error "Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined" and sometimes not posting the data to server or sending the request as normal POST request.

I guess the Ajax.BeginForm submit is not bind to javascript events when loaded through Jquery.Ajax. How to bind the submit here?

Answer (score 0):

**Issue**: "Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined"

This precisely is because something is wrong with project setting.
Try **Clean -> Rebuild -> Build**.
If still, the problem persists just project settings or web.config file.